# Magento 2 : Error occure model class does not extend \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Tags: magento2.3

[image: controller class][image: collection class][image: my resource class code:][image: my model class code is here]**facing this error**

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): 
>   Magik\Helloworld\Model\Image does not extend
>   \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Comment: you are remove the generated folder and run the setup command ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can update your controller file Below way..

```
<?php
namespace Magik\Helloworld\Controller\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magik\Helloworld\Model\ImageFactory
     */

    protected $_modelImageFactory;

    /**
     * @param ImageFactory $modelImageFactory
     */

    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
         \Magik\Helloworld\Model\ImageFactory $modelImageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_modelImageFactory = $modelImageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // echo "Hello World";

        $imageModel = $this->_modelImageFactory->create();


        //Get image collection
        // $newsCollection = $imageModel->getCollection();
        // foreach ($newsCollection as $item) {
        //  echo "<pre>";
        //  print_r($item->getData());
        //  echo "</pre>";

        // }
         // Load the item with ID is 1
        $item = $imageModel->load(1);
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($item->getData());

        // // Get news collection
        $newsCollection = $imageModel->getCollection();
        // // Load all data of collection
        var_dump($newsCollection->getData());


        // return $this->_pageFactory->create();

    }
}
```

and run again below command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**And Finally Result:**

[image]

Comment: which answer..?

Comment: I did it but couldn't work again give same error.

Comment: okk I will compile again.

Comment: It again gives same error. What will I do.